# DBAL Querybuilder not updating

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder, dbal

I am trying to update a record with the DBAL Query builder and it does not seem to be working. The `data` column that I am trying to set will only work if I replace the `test` example value I have here with a number.

In that case it will update my record perfectly fine.

Even if I use `setParameter` for it as well it will silently fail.

```
$queryBuilder = $this->connection
                ->update($this->table)
                ->where('id = ?')
                ->set('data', 'test')
                ->setParameter(0, $sessionId);
```

Am I mis-using this or is something else going on?

**Edit:**

The insert statement works perfectly fine:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->connection
                ->insert($this->table)
                ->values([
                    'id' => '?',
                    'secure' => '?',
                    'modified' => '?',
                    'lifetime' => '?',
                    'user_hash' => '?',
                    'data' => '?',
                ])
                ->setParameter(0, $sessionId)
                ->setParameter(1, 'y')
                ->setParameter(2, time())
                ->setParameter(3, $this->minutes)
                ->setParameter(4, 'test')
                ->setParameter(5, $data);
        }
```

Comment: Is the column restricted to numeric values, perhaps?

Comment: @Jolta no, not at all and my insert statement works fine which can insert all kinds of mixed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use parameters in `update` the same way you use it in `insert`:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->connection
            ->update($this->table)
            ->set('data', '?')
            ->where('id = ?')
            ->setParameter(0, 'test')
            ->setParameter(1, $sessionId);
```

Comment: You swapped the `set` and `where`. I tried it and it works now, guess this is pretty important. You also can absolutely not swap the `setParameters` even if you update their corresponding number correctly. Guess you are my guardian angel today. Thanks for helping out(again lol).

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't. Are you saying `->set('data', ':data')->setParameter('data', 'test')`  isn't working?

Comment: You are not mixing positional and named parameters, are you?

Comment: Deleted the comment. Figured it out now. Thanks for helping.